# Hide AdSense or GoogleAdmanager ad unit when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, adsense, google-dfp, google-ad-manager

I am trying to hide a div containing an AdSense unit when the ad itself is clicked. I am trying with onclick="... with no success.

It is not fraud and the ad do not cover any kind of content.
I just want to hide this particular ad unit if clicked and compress the div.
Thank you for your support.

Andrea

Comment: you can't do that

Comment: But I did it :)

Comment: wow, any details? Did you get inside a friendly frame and manually attached your handler?

Comment: I posted an answer to explain to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

First the ads:

```
<body-5 id="target">
<!-- /XXXX/leaderboard -->
<div id='div-gpt-ad-XXXXXXXXXXX-0' class="adsbygoogle" style='height:90px; width:728px;'>
<script>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-XXXXXXXXXXX-0'); });
setInterval(function(){googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]);}, 60000);
</script>
</div>
</body-5>
```

Then the script to hide the ads:

```
<!-- HIDE ADS -->
<script src="/script/iframe/jquery.iframetracker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
interval_id = window.setInterval(function() {
//check if iframe exists
if( jQuery('.adsbygoogle div').length > 0 ) {
    jQuery('.adsbygoogle div').iframeTracker({
        blurCallback: function(){
// Do something when the iframe is clicked
    $('#target').slideUp( 2000 );
        }
    });
    //clear the interval
    // clearInterval(interval_id);
    }
},300);
});
</script>
```